# Raspberry problems turning LEDs on

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, led

My problem is that when using a pin from Rapsberry model A v1.1 with 3.3V or 5V, the LEDs are turning on but when I try to create a script to use GPIO 18 for example it doesnt work. Can you help me please? I will attach photos.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
try:
    while True:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(5, 1)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(5, 0)
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

[image: GPIO PIN 5 (physical pin 18)]

[image: 3.3 VDC PIN (physical pin 17)]

As you can see in the first image is the GPIO 5, and does not work, in the second image is the 3.3VDC pin and the LEDs are turning on.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the yellow box in your pinout picture above, this is not the official GPIO numbering, try https://pinout.xyz/ for the official one. According to that one, GPIO5 is pin29 and pin5 is GPIO3.